# Is there a way to return from the containing block of a map in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, return

I'm trying to implement a function which checks whether a list of letters are all present in a word.

```
function wordHasLatters(word,letters){
    let wordChars={};
    word.split("").map(c=>wordChars[c]=true);
    let ok=true;
    letters.split("").map(l=>ok=ok&&(wordChars[l]!=undefined));
    return ok;
}
```

It is all relatively elegant with using maps. What bothers me is that I cannot return from the second map if I detect that a letter is not present. So I have to use a variable and return this. This is two extra lines in the code.

Is there a way to optimize this code?

Comment: A break won't return from the containing block. I would still have to maintain a variable and return that.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd read more than the title...

Comment: What is this trend with people using `.map()` and ignoring its result. This is either a case for `.reduce()` or for imperative loops. Using `.map()` is just so odd here.

Comment: Indeed, both uses of `.map()` are incorrect. `.map()` should only be used to convert one array to another array of the same length, by returning an array element value in each iteration, and then assigning the result of `.map()` to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 const wordHasLetters = (word,letters) => letters.every(letter => word.includes(letter));
```

or use a plain old for loop:

```
 function wordHasLetters(word, letters){
   const hash = {};
   for(var char of word)
     hash[char] = true;
   for(var letter of letters)
     if(!hash[letter]) return false;
   return true;
 }
```

Or using a Set:

```
 function wordHasLetters(word, letters){
   const set = new Set(letters);
   for(var char of word){
     set.delete(char);
     if(!set.size) return true;
   }
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: The first one is just wonderful.